# SQL - cleaner way to select result based on max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query that joins to several tables. Based on the column value of one table, I would like the key value of another table. But, when this key value is joined to another table (with the purpose of identifying different date values for that key), several dates appear. I would like to return the Key Value whose date is most recent when joined to another table. I have a query that works, but it is very redundant, as the sub-query is nearly identical to the main query. I didn't know if there was a technique or better way to achieve this.

Example query:

```
SELECT distinct TableA.key
    FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b 
        ON a.key = b.Key    
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.Key2 = c.Key2
INNER JOIN TableD d ON b.Key = d.Key
WHERE b.column1 = XYZ        
AND c.column1 = 123
and d.date = 

(SELECT max(d.date)
    FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b 
        ON a.Key = b.Key   
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.Key2 = c.Key2
INNER JOIN TableD d ON b.Key = d.Key
WHERE b.column1 = XYZ          
AND c.column1 = 123

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `Top 1 with ties` order by date desc

```
SELECT distinct TOP 1 with ties TableA.key
    FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b 
        ON a.key = b.Key    
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.Key2 = c.Key2
INNER JOIN TableD d ON b.Key = d.Key
WHERE b.column1 = XYZ        
AND c.column1 = 123
order by  d.date desc
```

Comment: I have never seen the "top x with ties" option before.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: There is one typo in this answer... `DISTINCT` needs to come before `TOP 1 WITH TIES` instead of after.